# Where can I find documentation or source code for udev properties?

Tags: kernel, udev

Specifically, I've been trying to find what the possible values are for the property UDISKS_PARTITION_FLAGS. It seems to be set to "boot" if the partition has the boot/active flag set, and unset if not, but I'd like to find some documentation to that effect.

Google is unhelpful. I've downloaded and searched both the systemd source (which includes udev) and the kernel source, but found no match for the string "UDISKS_PARTITION_FLAGS". Where is the value of this property set? Where is it documented?

**EDIT:**

I've been using pyudev to access this property, and I thought it got them from udev. In response to the comments I've tried to get it to show up using

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/sda1 --attribute-walk
```

but I can't find the property in question there. However, looking at the link provided by slm in the comments, I found this command:

```
udisks --show-info /dev/sda1
```

The output has a `partition` section, where `flags` has the value `boot`. So it's really this value I want to find the documentation or source code for. It is only present for the partition that has the boot flag set.

Comment: Most udev rules reference data it's getting from sysfs. I'm not finding anything related underneath `/sys` on my systems with the word "flag" or "flags" in it. It might be something the distribution defined specifically for their purposes. What distro is this on?

Comment: @Joel Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: Take a look at this script, it shows how they're getting what you're asking about: http://forums.opensuse.org/english/other-forums/development/programming-scripting/print-475610-lspart-alternative-fdisk-l.html

Comment: @slm Getting the value is not the problem. I want to know how and under what circumstances it's *set* by the kernel or udev or whatever it is that originally sets that value.

Comment: OK, I just installed Ubuntu 12. I want to trace it back, where are you initially seeing that referenced in udev?

Comment: @LauritzV.Thaulow - OK, sorry about that.

Comment: @JoelDavis - you didn't have Ubuntu installed already? 8-). Being on this site I've had to keep another 5 OSes around just so I can see what ppl are asking about 8-).

Comment: @Joel See my update to the question.

Comment: @slm Ha yeah I actually haven't even used Ubuntu for myself at all. I've been at the terminal a few times on other people's machines, but never more than that. Which is kind of surprising considering how often it gets mentioned and I know people who are card carrying members of the cult of Shuttleworth. I'll probably leave this installed so I have some vague point of reference for it. Only took me, what, 6 or 7 years to get around to installing it?

Comment: @Joel I think I've found it myself. I'll post a self-answer in a minute.

Comment: Cool, synergy/collaboration wins again (well your and slm's synergy, I just basically installed an OS).

Answer (score 1):

The udev properties with the UDISKS prefix is set by [udisks 1.0.4](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/), in [src/helpers/partutil.c:1246](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/udisks/tree/src/helpers/partutil.c?id=36329d9548aa9d4016f919f4a19ed7c0d1fbeb11#n1242). It is then picked up by udev somehow and stored in the property `UDISKS_PARTITION_FLAGS`, which can be found with this command:

```
udevadm info --name=/dev/sda1 --query=property
```

[Here](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/1.0.5/Device.html#Device%3aPartitionFlags) is the documentation for the property. Following the link to PartitionCreate shows that it may only be set to the value "boot" if the partitioning scheme is mbr, which is in agreement with the source code linked to in the first paragraph.

**EDIT:** Updated answer after comment from don_crissti.

Comment: @don_crissti Nice catch, I've updated my answer. Thank you! :)